# MySql, Optional Categories, Sub Categories and Sub Sub Categories for products

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say a the database has a table of members.  Before each member adds a product they can create and their own category, then a sub category and even a sub sub  category.  A product they add may only belong to a category, but another one could belong to a sub sub category.  I'm trying to think of the most efficient way of doing this.  I know the example below  isn't probably correct but hopefully explains what my thinking is.

```
Member 
MemberID  Name  
-----------------------
Member_Category
CategoryID, MemberID, CategoryName
------------------------------------
Member_SubCategory
SubCategoryID, CategoryID, SubCategoryName
---------------------------------
Member_SubSubCategory
SubSubCategoryID, SubCategoryID, SubSubCategoryName
----------------------------
Product
ProductID, MemberID, CategoryID, SubCategoryID, SubSubCategoryID, ProductName, Cost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the product should have only one 'categoryID' column, no subs.

If product can be in more than one category at the same time, better put that in a separate table 'products2categies' with 'productID' and 'columnID' columns.

Second there are different ways to implement a tree structure in a DB. I will offer you the most simple.
In 'categories' table create this structure: 'categoryID', 'category_name' and 'parentID' columns. First two are self-explainatory, third point to the parent category. If this is a main category, make 'parentID' = 0.

For more on tree structures in DB see this [What are the known ways to store a tree structure in a relational DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362669/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-a-tree-structure-in-a-relational-db)

```
Member 
MemberID  Name  
-----------------------
Member_Category
CategoryID, MemberID, CategoryName, ParentID
------------------------------------
Product
ProductID, MemberID, CategoryID, ProductName, Cost
```

Comment: So, in the category table if I had an entry of Wine with an id of 1, then created two more categories e.g. red and white....both their parent id's would be 1.  Also because the table will be used by many members the columns would be CatID MemberID Name ParentID.

Comment: Not too sure how this would be coded to add and fetch data. I guess if you wanted to give the user the top parent categories then you would pull out all those with a parent ID of 0, then to find the subcats find the fields which have the CatID in the ParentID....does that sound about right?  And sorry to go on...but this then means all Cats, Sub Cats...Sub Sub Cats....are all in one table.

Comment: Exactly all in one table, one column for category in the products table :) And you were right about what you said for adding the memberID in categories table in your previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for your time Yasen, you have been very helpful