# How to generate graphically tree with parent and child based on n level from database using array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, multiway-tree

I have following kind of data to table:

id      parent_id       child_id     level 
1         53987                  52548           1 
2         60764                  52548           2 
3         60764                  53987           1 
4         60764                  59695            2 
5         63457                 59695            1 
6        60764                 63457            1

So, how i can get data by recursively with level and store data to array like ['child_id','parent_id',level]. I need help for writting query and generate the tree.

The tree should be like :
[image]

Note: I can't change the database's table structure. I must need tree based on given table structure.

Comment: Provide more detail.. like what kind of output do you need.

Comment: May be this would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362669/what-are-the-known-ways-to-store-a-tree-structure-in-a-relational-db

Comment: @Tarun : I can't change the database's table structure. I must need tree based on given table structure.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @SandeepThakkar just keep searching recursively if you dont mind performance and cache the tree in your application code so you dont have to keep hitting DB to retrieve the tree.

Comment: For graphical generation of the tree, look at [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/gallery/)

Comment: Just consider all the entries with level 1. It will give you the required array.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Query:

```
select  id,
        `child_id`,
        `parent_id` , level
from    (select * from vtiger_ib_level
         order by parent_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '60764') initialisation
where   find_in_set(`parent_id`, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```